# How or add some information about user, into Firebase Firestore, and identify it by uid, from Firebase Auth on SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-authentication

[I need to send data ( first name, second name, bio... to Firebase Firestore collection, and find by uid ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P7Q2.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Please learn how to post and format your code on Stack Overflow. This will make life much easier for people who want to help you.